# Embed JNLP file in web page

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

I want to embed a JNLP file in web page but a problem occured when I enter the page.

An RuntimeException occured, `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

[Click here to see the exception window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd583.png)

after I click "details(D)",the problem shown on java console is

`Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/lqy-jnlp/Card.jar`

I have done the following things.

1. Sign my jar(Card.jar) file.
2. Encode the contents of the JNLP file using the Base64 scheme.
3. Add the persimmisons attribute in manifest file

I followed the steps on this [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html), but still cannot fix the 
problems.

---

Here is my html code

```
<html>
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'game.jnlp',
                      jnlp_embedded:'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'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
    </script>
</html>
```

---

Here is game.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="game.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Game</title>
    <vendor>Game</vendor>
</information>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.7+"
        href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
    <jar href="Card.jar" main="true" />

</resources>
<applet-desc 
     name="Dynamic Tree Demo Applet"
     main-class="MainTest"
     width="400"
     height="500">
 </applet-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is my jar's manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: Card Game
Permissions: all-permissons
Created-By: 1.7.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: MainTest
Codebase: *

Name: Card.class
SHA-256-Digest: C0mmndLFOcvB3Or0eUq45a79opI7q8a7xg97ykw7Stg=

Name: Deck.class
SHA-256-Digest: 4kvleZ87SC6uIpL6CiEFpIYyMu7B7OCeWW7pxAzLGFg=

Name: MainTest.class
SHA-256-Digest: y4IjMvSafZ/umVQF8prW2h6TJ0S+S4XlVhVmWHJQj/4=

Name: JBetCard.class
SHA-256-Digest: +l1YNANpFed84u2M8asoEGfX0OdgwosqsNbfQmbuXn4=
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of your jar’s manifest.

Comment: @VGR OK, the question has been edited.